# Raku type inference

Tags: type-inference, raku

Given:

```
sub abc(Int $n) { say $n }
```

If we pass a variable typed as `Str` to `abc` we get a compile-time error:

```
my Str $s = "123";   abc $s;
```

If we pass an untyped variable that holds a string, we get a runtime error:

```
my $s = "123";   abc $s;
```

C++ supports an `auto` keyword which allows for type inference.

Is it possible to define something like `auto` in Raku such that:

```
auto $s = "123";
```

would result in `$s` being typed as `Str`?

I.e. then we could do the following:

```
auto $s = "123";   abc $s;
```

And get a compile-time error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it possible to define something like `auto` in Perl 6

I think it is, sort of. But I'm going to have to translate your question into three different ones to provide a more useful answer.

For my answers to the first two questions below, please reference [a reddit comment I wrote about this](https://www.reddit.com/r/perl6/comments/6jh2bs/creating_a_simple_dsl_do_end/djeqlx4). My comment was in four parts, separated by horizontal rules. The first and last parts are relevant to your question.

## Is it possible to modify the Perl 6 language?

Yes.

You can more or less arbitrarily modify the Perl 6 language on the fly from userland code.

Quoting a bullet point from the first part of the comment I linked above:

- Internal slang DSLs built using grammars, like an external DSL, but mixed in with the standard Perl 6 grammar via the slang mechanism. These DSLs must be written to have at least some basic coordination with the standard Perl 6 grammar. Code written in such DSLs appears inline, indistinguishable from regular code. [Relevant slides](http://bduggan.github.io/fosdem-2017/#79).

Quoting a bit of the last part I wrote:

While slangs can be implemented ... they are not officially supported ... and are not as sugary as they need to be.

## Is it possible to write compile-time macros that communicate with the compiler?

Yes.

Unfortunately you can't yet define statement macros, which is what you'd need for a new type of variable declaration. Quoting the last section in the comment I linked above:

"The intended design options for situations where you want an internal DSL but it's too syntactically in conflict with standard Perl 6 to just use user defined routines and operators are ... Write an `is parsed` macro [or] Write a slang. Either of these can, in theory, parse any syntax you want. But `is parsed` macros haven't landed and look like they're at least a year or three away -- they're still just a design concept being discussed in [007](https://github.com/masak/007)."

## Is it possible to get new ideas into Perl 6?

Yes.

Just implement your idea and lobby for its inclusion. Possibly start with a slang. Possibly just directly hack on the entire compiler.

I'm being serious about that last point.

The Rakudo Perl 6 compiler is of course open source.

Much more importantly, it's mostly [written in Perl 6](https://perl6.party/post/Perl-6-is-written-in...-Perl-6). (And most of what isn't Perl 6 is nqp which is basically a subset of full Perl 6.)

## Conclusion

If you can write some basic Perl 6 code; are willing to [ask loads of questions on the freenode IRC channel #perl6-dev](https://kiwiirc.com/nextclient/irc.freenode.com/#perl6-dev); and are patient; then you should be able to implement just about any idea in Perl 6 and your `auto` idea seems relatively simple.

(Where by "relatively" I'm imagining a knowledgeable core dev might be able to do a proof of concept in a few hours assuming I've correctly understood the problems they'd face. And one day, when slangs and/or macros are more polished perhaps it would take about an hour.)

Answer (score 6):

What you are looking for is probably what we call [allomorphs](https://docs.perl6.org/language/glossary#Allomorph) in Perl6, types that can behave differently depending on the context. For the particular case you have posted, there's the [IntStr allomorph](https://docs.perl6.org/type/IntStr):

```
sub abc(Int $n) { say $n }
my IntStr $s = <123>;
abc $s; # prints 123
```

(Please note that it needs the [quote-words <>](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/%3C%20%3E) instead of the usual `""`). Allomorphs, in general, are subclassses of the classes they can be typecasted into; `IntStr` subclasses `Int` and `Str`. This can be done in general for any types you want to `auto`, as long as they are mutually convertible.

Another option, if you already know what you are going to get and what it is being turn into, is to [use coercion](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Signature#Coercion_Type):

```
sub bcd(Int(Str) $n) { say $n }
my $t = "123";
bcd $t; # prints 123
```

In this case, the string will be coerced to an `Int` in the [Capture](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Capture) before being used by the subroutine body.

Finally, you can use [the number contextualizer](https://docs.perl6.org/language/contexts#Number), as long as you use when the variable is effectively going to be used.

```
sub efg($n) { say +$n }
my Int $u = 123;
my Str $v = "123";
efg $u;
efg $v;
```

`+` puts a variable in a numeric context, automatically converting it to a number. You can even turn that into a signature constraint if you want to restrict it to either Int or Str

```
sub xyz($n where $_ ~~ Int | Str ) { say +$n }
xyz $u;
xyz $v;
xyz $t;
xyz $s;
```

(It's using the variables defined above) Here it will work no matter if the variable does not have a type assigned (like `$t`, or has been defined as `IntStr`, `Int` or `Str`). As long as it can be smartmatched to `Int` or `Str`, it will be fed into the sub body and turned into a number via contextualization.

Full program is [here](https://github.com/JJ/my-perl6-examples/blob/master/intstr.p6), just in case you want to download and check it.

Comment: This is cool and thanks for sharing jjmerelo! However, my intention really was to ask about type inference as it exists in C++, C#, etc. :-)

Comment: @dharmatech as far as I can tell, type inference occurs at assignment (the famous duck typing). From them on, it's type casting or type coertion.

Comment: The problem is that things you want to constrain to strings shouldn't have an escape hatch into another type.

Answer (score 5):

I just want to mention [Proxies](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Proxy). These work at the container level and only at run-time. But give some ability to control or track what's going into a variable.

```
sub auto($v?) is rw {
    my $val = $v;
    Proxy.new(
        FETCH => -> $, { $val },
        STORE => -> $, $new-val {
            die "You canna change type from {$val.WHAT.^name} to {$new-val.WHAT.^name}"
                unless $new-val.WHAT ~~ $val.WHAT;
            $val = $new-val;
        }
    )
}

my $i := auto(11);
$i = 69;
say $i;
$i = 'blah'; # Boom
```

Proxys can be used to implement something like the `auto` types, but only at run-time and only at the container level. They're also not quite as water-tight, as the container associated with a variable can change. For example, using the bind `:=` operator

```
$i := 'he he'; # changed container
```